# Casting from base type to derived type in c#

Tags: c#, oop

So I know you can't cast from base type to derived type because an Animal might not be a Cat etc etc.

Given that, can you suggest a better way to implement this code, and avoid having to repeat the operator declaration and instantiate new objects?

```
class scientific_number
{
    public decimal value;
    public int precision;
    public static implicit operator scientific_number(decimal value)
    {
        return new scientific_number() { value = value, precision = 0 };
    }
    public static implicit operator scientific_number(int value)
    {
        return new scientific_number() { value = (decimal)value, precision = 0 };
    }
    public static implicit operator scientific_number(double value)
    {
        return new scientific_number() { value = (decimal)value, precision = 0 };
    }
}
class amu : scientific_number 
{
    public static implicit operator amu(scientific_number scientific_number)
    {
        return new amu() { value = scientific_number.value, precision = scientific_number.precision };
    }
    public static implicit operator amu(decimal value)
    {
        return new amu() { value = value, precision = 0 };
    }
    public static implicit operator amu(int value)
    {
        return new amu() { value = (decimal)value, precision = 0 };
    }
    public static implicit operator amu(double value)
    {
        return new amu() { value = (decimal)value, precision = 0 };
    }

    public kg ToEarthKg()
    {
        return this.value / 0.00000000000000000000000000166053886;
    }
}
class kg : scientific_number
{
    public static implicit operator kg(scientific_number scientific_number)
    {
        return new kg() { value = scientific_number.value, precision = scientific_number.precision };
    }
    public static implicit operator kg(decimal value)
    {
        return new kg() { value = value, precision = 0 };
    }
    public static implicit operator kg(int value)
    {
        return new kg() { value = (decimal)value, precision = 0 };
    }
    public static implicit operator kg(double value)
    {
        return new kg() { value = (decimal)value, precision = 0 };
    }
}
```

Comment: You you explain what you are trying to achieve with this class hierarchy? (Rooted in `scientific_number`.)

Comment: Have you tried writing some real code with this? Implicit cast operators on reference types seems iffy. Especially `implicit operator amu(scientific_number)`.

Comment: @Richard - trying to create classes for various units of measurement, which will all be scientific numbers (precision-specific). So I can declare "class proton { public amu mass; }" instead of "class proton { public decimal mass; }"

Comment: @Henk - nope I haven't run this code yet. Want to remove the duplication before building much more on it.

Comment: Do some testing first. You may need a bigger overhaul than you think.

Comment: Inheritance is likely to wrong approach. Consider composition. Also have you looked at F# with its native support for [units of measurement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243(v=vs.100).aspx)? (Any approach in C# will inevitably be limited by the capabilities – especially inability to specialise generics – of the C# object model. The need to repeat here is an example of this.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll check out F# but as a recent C# convert I'll probably struggle. Maybe inheritance is wrong (I just wanted to be able to declare properties in their standard unit & have nice conversion functions), and a "unit" property of scientific_number would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

> So I know you can't cast from base type to derived type because an Animal might not be a Cat etc etc.

Wrong.

You can, if the object is not of the target type you'll get an exception.

If you use the `as` operator and the target type is a reference type you'll get null if the cast cannot be performed.

So

```
Animal d = new Dog();

var c = (Cat)d;   // Will throw

var c1 = d as Cat; // Will return null (assuming Dog is a reference type).
```

Comment: While technically correct, it doesn't answer the question about the operators.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The operator approach is based on a false premise. This is an example of an X Y problem, but at least X has been expressed.

Comment: I am not sure this is the case. The OP wants implicit operators from integral types (and the base class type) to each derived type of his class hierarchy. Even with your explanation it is still required to declare those operators for each derived class.

Comment: "Animal d = new Dog();" is not casting a Animal as a Dog, but a Dog as an Animal.

Now if I could somehow say "GetDog() { return new Animal(); }" and have the Animal implicitly cast as a Dog, then my life would be a lot easier. I understand why this isn't possible by default but in some cases it would be useful, and OK, if the framework permitted it.

With respect to the OP - specifically I would like to avoid repeating identical operator declarations, as per the DRY principle.

Comment: @BrendanHill The constructor (1st code line0 is not a cast, those are in the following lines (showing failure cases).